# Oracle SQL - "Not a group by expression" after adding CASE statements

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case

I have long query to which I had to add two new CASE statements -

```
SELECT nt.COSTCENTER,
s.DAD,
s.DIVISION, 
nt.DISPENSER,
UPPER(nt.TINTERSERIALNBR),
COUNT(*)OVER (PARTITION BY nt.COSTCENTER) AS NumOfDispensers,
nt.CLRNTSYS,
SUM(CASE WHEN
(nt.CLRNTSYS ='CCE' AND (nt.BOOKDATE >= '01-JAN-17' AND nt.BOOKDATE <= '31-DEC-17')) 
THEN nt.GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS CCEGallons2017,
SUM(CASE WHEN
(nt.CLRNTSYS ='BAC' AND (nt.BOOKDATE >= '01-JAN-17' AND nt.BOOKDATE <= '31-DEC-17'))
THEN nt.GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS BACGallons2017,
SUM(CASE WHEN
(nt.CLRNTSYS ='CCE' AND (nt.BOOKDATE >= '01-JAN-18' AND nt.BOOKDATE <= '31-DEC-18')) 
THEN nt.GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS CCEGallons2018,
SUM(CASE WHEN
(nt.CLRNTSYS ='BAC' AND (nt.BOOKDATE >= '01-JAN-18' AND nt.BOOKDATE <= '31-DEC-18'))
THEN nt.GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS BACGallons2018,
CASE WHEN to_char(tm.DNRDATE,'YYYY') = '2017' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END DNR2017,
CASE WHEN to_char(tm.DNRDATE,'YYYY') = '2018' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END DNR2018
FROM MQ_CDS_NETTRAN nt
INNER JOIN MQCCNSTORE s
ON nt.COSTCENTER = s.COSTCENTER
INNER JOIN TINTER_MASTER tm
ON UPPER(nt.TINTERSERIALNBR) = UPPER(tm.SERIALNBR)
WHERE nt.BOOKDATE >= '01-JAN-17'
AND nt.CLRNTSYS IN ('CCE','BAC')
AND nt.TRANCODE = 'DISP'
AND UPPER(nt.DISPENSER) <> 'BYHAND'
AND UPPER(nt.DISPENSER) <> 'STANDALONE'
AND tm.DECOMMDATE IS NULL
GROUP BY nt.COSTCENTER, nt.DISPENSER, UPPER(nt.TINTERSERIALNBR), nt.CLRNTSYS,
s.DAD, s.DIVISION
ORDER BY nt.COSTCENTER, nt.DISPENSER, UPPER(nt.TINTERSERIALNBR), nt.CLRNTSYS;
```

These are the two CASE lines I added to the query:

```
CASE WHEN to_char(tm.DNRDATE,'YYYY') = '2017' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END DNR2017,
CASE WHEN to_char(tm.DNRDATE,'YYYY') = '2018' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END DNR2018
```

And when I try to run the query, I get "Not a group by expression."  Prior to adding those two lines, the query ran just fine.  How to best correct this?

Comment: In addition to the answer, please please PLEASE do not rely on implicit conversion between strings and dates. Instead, (assuming that your nt.bookdate column is of DATE datatype), you should use either `to_date()` or the ANSI `DATE` literal, e.g. either `to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` or `DATE '2018-01-01'. With your current query, if the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter was changed (e.g. after running `alter session set nls_date_format = dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss`), your query may error. Always be explicit, and that way your code should run regardless of nls settings.

Answer (score 4):

You need to let `CASE WHEN` add in `group by`, Because `CASE WHEN` isn't aggregate function.

```
SELECT nt.COSTCENTER,
    s.DAD,
    s.DIVISION, 
    nt.DISPENSER,
    UPPER(nt.TINTERSERIALNBR),
    COUNT(*)OVER (PARTITION BY nt.COSTCENTER) AS NumOfDispensers,
    nt.CLRNTSYS,
    SUM(CASE WHEN
    (nt.CLRNTSYS ='CCE' AND (nt.BOOKDATE >= '01-JAN-17' AND nt.BOOKDATE <= '31-DEC-17')) 
    THEN nt.GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS CCEGallons2017,
    SUM(CASE WHEN
    (nt.CLRNTSYS ='BAC' AND (nt.BOOKDATE >= '01-JAN-17' AND nt.BOOKDATE <= '31-DEC-17'))
    THEN nt.GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS BACGallons2017,
    SUM(CASE WHEN
    (nt.CLRNTSYS ='CCE' AND (nt.BOOKDATE >= '01-JAN-18' AND nt.BOOKDATE <= '31-DEC-18')) 
    THEN nt.GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS CCEGallons2018,
    SUM(CASE WHEN
    (nt.CLRNTSYS ='BAC' AND (nt.BOOKDATE >= '01-JAN-18' AND nt.BOOKDATE <= '31-DEC-18'))
    THEN nt.GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS BACGallons2018,
    CASE WHEN to_char(tm.DNRDATE,'YYYY') = '2017' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END DNR2017,
    CASE WHEN to_char(tm.DNRDATE,'YYYY') = '2018' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END DNR2018
FROM MQ_CDS_NETTRAN nt
INNER JOIN MQCCNSTORE s ON nt.COSTCENTER = s.COSTCENTER
INNER JOIN TINTER_MASTER tm ON UPPER(nt.TINTERSERIALNBR) = UPPER(tm.SERIALNBR)
WHERE 
        nt.BOOKDATE >= '01-JAN-17'
    AND nt.CLRNTSYS IN ('CCE','BAC')
    AND nt.TRANCODE = 'DISP'
    AND UPPER(nt.DISPENSER) <> 'BYHAND'
    AND UPPER(nt.DISPENSER) <> 'STANDALONE'
    AND tm.DECOMMDATE IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    nt.COSTCENTER, 
    nt.DISPENSER, 
    UPPER(nt.TINTERSERIALNBR),
    nt.CLRNTSYS,
    s.DAD, 
    s.DIVISION,
    CASE WHEN to_char(tm.DNRDATE,'YYYY') = '2017' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END,
    CASE WHEN to_char(tm.DNRDATE,'YYYY') = '2018' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
ORDER BY nt.COSTCENTER, nt.DISPENSER, UPPER(nt.TINTERSERIALNBR), nt.CLRNTSYS;
```

Comment: That seems to be working - I was thrown off by it saying "NOT a group by expression" as opposed to them actually being a group by expression that needs to be added to the GROUP BY section.